# Issue while running Scala Integration Tests From Maven

Tags: scala, maven

I wanted a guidance on running integration tests in Scala. I have a Maven based Scala project with the following versions

```
   java version "1.8.0_311"
   Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL
   Apache Maven 3.6.3
```

When I build and run my code using mvn clean install, I get this error:

```
com.foo.bar.MyIntegrationTest *** ABORTED ***
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load a Suite class that was discovered in the runpath: com.foo.bar.MyIntegrationTest
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$.getSuiteInstance(DiscoverySuite.scala:81)
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$$anonfun$1.apply(DiscoverySuite.scala:38)
  at org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$$anonfun$1.apply(DiscoverySuite.scala:37)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
```

I am able run these tests via Intellij, but not by a command line. The suggestions that I have across in the community are mostly about changes in the IDE, but any suggestions on how do I address this from the Maven command line?

Thanks,
Prabal

Comment: [this](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/806) might help! briefly, you might have an identical description for 2 tests (there are also other possibilities you can find out on that page). while running your tests on IntelliJ, the IDE might take care of running each test suite or each file independently providing classpaths, etc. so this might be the issue.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to solve this?